# good source for learning continuity,discontinuity

Tags: soft-question, continuity

What is a good online source, sites for learning continuity (specifically) . i have learnt limits and differentiation problem lies within the continuity. Any good websites(only) for learning this . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is one tutorial I used when learning.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Continuity.aspx)